# how to setup openvpn on amazon ec2 small windows instance with static key

Tags: windows-server-2003, amazon-ec2, openvpn

I have a small ec2 windows instance which means its windows server 2003.
I need to be able to resolve the instance from my windows machine at home through a vpn

I have determined http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html is close to what I want.  All I need is a simple point to point vpn from my machine to the server.  One concern I have is that the client (my home machine) has a dynamic ip which I can imagine is a problem?

So far I have been unable to get openvpn to connect.  Services on both machines say "Current State: Connecting" indefinitely.

Here is the output on the server:

```
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 OpenVPN 2.1.4 i686-pc-mingw32 [SSL] [LZO2] [PKCS11] built on Nov  8 2010
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 Static Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 Static Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 Static Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 Static Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 LZO compression initialized
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 TAP-WIN32 device [Local Area Connection 2] opened: \\.\Global\{76816B22-25B1-4669-9F96-833967531B88}.tap
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 TAP-Win32 Driver Version 9.7 
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 TAP-Win32 MTU=1500
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 Notified TAP-Win32 driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.7.0.5/255.255.255.252 on interface {76816B22-25B1-4669-9F96-833967531B88} [DHCP-serv: 10.7.0.6, lease-time: 31536000]
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 NOTE: FlushIpNetTable failed on interface [65540] {76816B22-25B1-4669-9F96-833967531B88} (status=259) : No more data is available.  
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1545 D:1450 EF:45 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '981d55a0'
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '812fd57b'
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]:1194
Thu Mar 31 18:11:05 2011 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
```

And the server config:

```
dev tun
ifconfig 10.7.0.5 10.7.0.6
secret static.key

port 1194
proto udp
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status server-tcp.log
verb 3
```

What I tried:

The two ips in ifconfig were selected using the openvpn --show-valid-subnets command (I'm not sure if that step was legit)

I thought the port might be blocked so I also made sure udp port 1194 was open in amazon security group.  Did not help.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details. Show both server and client config files. Are you sure that your client is connecting to correct address?